# How to hide a div of html using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view for show a model.That when change dropdown, i show a special DIV.

I have same property in divs.

```
 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EstateType)
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EstateType)
<div id="apartment">
  <div class="row">
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Space)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Space)

   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Area)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Area)

   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Rooms)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Rooms)

   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Floor)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Floor)
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="shop"  style="display: none">
  <div class="row">
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Space)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Space)

   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Area)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Area)

   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Rooms)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Rooms)

   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Floor)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Floor)
  </div>
 </div>
```

and in change of dropdown

```
 $('#EstateType').change(function () {
  var item = $(this).val();
  switch (item) {
    case "Apartments":
      $("#apartment").css("display", "block");
      $("#shop").css("display", "none");
     break;
     case "Shop":
      $("#apartment").css("display", "none");
      $("#shop").css("display", "block");
     break;
```

I fill controll but when post data in Controller, data in empty when shop div in Block.

Can i remove apartment div when show shop div?

Comment: [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Comment: Thanks, but when i use hide, it is set display:none.

Comment: you want to remove "#apartment" div from your html?

Comment: Yes, i want remove from html, but i want show again when user select apartment in dropdown.

Comment: If you remove permanent then you can user `$("#DIV_ID").remove();`

Comment: But he is used remove then he couldn't show again when select that div right @ar.gorgin

Comment: @ar.gorgin If you remove html div so can used $("#DIV_ID").remove(); 
and hide the div so used $("#DIV_ID").hide();
but if you remove div one time so i think its not possible show again when user select appartment in HTML

Comment: I think you can use disable the textbox whose value should not be passed like `$("#apartment").hide().find('input').prop('disabled', true);$("#shop").show().find('input').prop('disabled', false);`

Comment: @Satpal : Thanks a lot :), i use this

Comment: Yes, i use `$("#apartment").hide().find('input').prop('disabled', true);$("#shop").show().find('input').prop('disabled', false);` Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Satpal : plz add this for answer.

Comment: @ar.gorgin, Added it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want values to be passed, You can use `disabled` property.

Here is an code example:

```
$("#apartment")
    .hide() //hide appartment div
    .find('input') //find all inputs in the div
    .prop('disabled', true); //disable them

$("#shop")
    .show() //show shop div
    .find('input') //find all inputs in the div
    .prop('disabled', false); //enable them
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below code to hide a div in jquery

```
$("#DIV_ID").hide();
```

Comment: thanks, but this set `display:none`, like i use `$("#apartment").css("display", "none");` , i want to hide div in html

Comment: Those tow are leads you to hide the div or some given tag only. What are you expecting then this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 2 was by using jQuery

Method 1: Using the method hide()

**Syntax:**

```
$(selector).hide();
```

Method 2: Using the method css(). By this using this we will apply styles dynamically.

**Syntax:**

```
$(selector).css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: Thanks , but i want to display in html.

Answer (score 0):

You need use Remove method in JQuery
like:

```
$( "#DIV_ID" ).remove();
```

Comment: Thanks, but i want show again when user select apartment.

Comment: you can or Hide it ON PAGE (but it still be in html) or REMOVE it from HTML
You can Hide in HTML

Comment: Just Remove it - and hten when you will need show it again - create new div with JQUERY